# How to use environment variables to run node app in atom IDE

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, atom-editor

I have node project that contains .bat file to set all the env variables & then it run my server.js .
How can i achieve the same using IDE?
Currently when i am trying to run the code from atom ide its giving error for those environment variables not set as they are required to run my project.

While running from command prompt i can simply run the .bat file which sets all the environment variables required for my project followed by "node server.js" command to run my project.

But from atom IDE when i run server.js it is not able to find the environment variables. How can i define/set these environment variables so that the atom IDE can read it & use them when i run server.js.??

Comment: What do you mean by running it from Atom? Btw, Atom is not an IDE.

Answer (score -1):

Install XAtom NodeJS Debugger: apm install xatom-debug-nodejs

Toolbar will be shown,

Choose your project,
click on Node.js button and in the popup shown configure your project setting and
environment variables. 
[image]